# Does system call flush() return before or after TCP ACK received?

Tags: tcp, linux-kernel, flush

When i send data using `send()` and call blocking system call `flush()`, does flush return :

- after corresponding TCP-ACK is received?

  or
- after data is sent over network?

Comment: There *is* no `flush()` system call in Linux.

Answer (score 0):

As @caf comments, there is no `flush` system call in Linux. Furthermore there is no mechanism in Linux to wait for a TCP ACK to be received. When you `send` data to the network it has entered the kernel's network buffers, no more guarantees are available. When the kernel receives and ACK the data has entered the receive window on the remote host, no more guarantee is available (critically it may not have reached the application on the remote host).

If you wish to ensure delivery of data sent over TCP then you should have the receiver acknowledge the data at the application layer by sending a reply.